# Crosscompiling using CMake

Tags: c++, linux, linker, cmake

this is my CMakeLists.txt

It leads to the error message "cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a".
That seems for me to be the wrong path as the prefix CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is not evaluated. 
Why the heck?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Find library delivers the correct path! 
/home/micha/projects/Raspberry/rootfs/usr/lib/libpthread.so

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/micha/ExtPackSrcs/CrossCompilerPi/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-cc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/micha/ExtPackSrcs/CrossCompilerPi/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-c++)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/micha/projects/Raspberry/rootfs)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

project(arrg)

find_library(LIB_PTHREAD pthread)
message("LIB_PTHREAD " ${LIB_PTHREAD})

add_executable(arrg
      main.cpp
      )

target_link_libraries(arrg
  ${LIB_PTHREAD}
)
```

Comment: So the file in question lives at `/home/micha/projects/Raspberry/rootfs/libpthread_nonshared.a`?

Comment: no, its in "/home/micha/projects/Raspberry/rootfs/usr/lib/libpthread.so". This path is found via the find_library command